# Is secure communication without public-key crytography feasible?

Tags: public-key, terminology

We all know about public-key cryptosystems, and we know some of these are computationally secure (for the time being, of course).

Are there any algorithms out there which allow safe communication between peers in a non “public/private” key fashion? If so, I would like to know some of these. If not, does any kind of formal demonstration of the infeasibility of such algorithms exist?

Comment: Would you accept quantum crypto?

Comment: Or simply symmetric crypto? I don't see anything in the question that rules that out.

Comment: Would you accept [TLS-PSK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TLS-PSK) with `TLS_PSK_WITH_AES_128_GCM_SHA256`? [RFC 5487](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc5487#page-4)

Comment: Something like TLS-PSK, but without pre-shared keys. I'm interested in the demonstration of infeasibility of secure communications with these constraints.

Comment: The whole point of public keys and signature is to verify identity of the parties and to agree on keys without trusted third parties. PKI allows the CA to sign keys offline and thus associate keys with entities. If you're willing to assume an online trusted third party, which shares a symmetric key with every participant, you indeed wouldn't need all this public key stuff.

Comment: "Are there any algorithms out there which allow safe communication between peers in a non public/private key fashion?" $\:$ Yes, AES[-SIV](http://web.cs.ucdavis.edu/~rogaway/papers/siv.pdf) is such an algorithm. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Just to be sure you´re not expecting us to replace Google… ***What research have you done?***

Comment: @e-sushi I did a fair amount of research, but as you can guess, I'm not an expert and don't know the terminology that well in order to search for the right things. Anyway Ricky Demer pointed my in the right direction, so thanks!!

Comment: @AlbertoFernández Oh, ok… just asked to find out where you got stuck to better grasp what info exactly you might be looking for. Welcome to Crypto.SE by the way! ;)

Comment: What are your actual assumptions about the initial setup? What do parties know of each other? Is there some trusted third party, a public bullet board, a PKI with certificates? Basically: If you got no prior knowledge of each other and trust no one else, you can't build any form of authentication.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious answer is symmetric keys.  You'll find that this is actually what asymmetric keys end up used for, exchanging symmetric keys.  If you trust someone who gives you a key, and you can trust that no one else has it, that's about as secure as it gets.  The difficult of satisfying those requirements is why we have asymmetric keys.